# Reasons to use "red herrings"?

Tags: screenwriting, tropes

I don't see any analytical literature about the usefulness of red herrings as a TV trope. What are some reasons to use them? I'm assuming there's more to it than just bored writers trying to amuse themselves to the detriment of the reader.

The one I can think of is - generally you build anticipation in a plot by making the viewer/reader subconsciously establish a pattern through repeated exposure to consistent cause and effect. Then to evoke a dramatic / emotional shock you mislead them by giving a cause that fails to provide the anticipated effect. Moreover, you leave the viewer anxious about the climax by sewing a seed of doubt that the effect is not a foregone conclusion.

Is this the basic intention? Or are their others?

Example: I create a highlights video of soccer matches where my favorite team keeps starting a match badly conceding goals, but always makes a comeback and wins each game. Then just as it's getting predictable, you throw a red herring in by showing highlights of a match where they fail to make a comeback and the viewer is jarred with disappointment. Subsequent match highlights will then keep the viewer on edge by not knowing which way the next one will go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you quite have the sense of what a red herring is. It really isn't a general plot device. It is more a specific technique in a puzzle kind of plot, such as a who-done-it mystery. It is something that suggest, and leads the reader to believe, that the gardener did it, when in fact it was the butler who it. The entire plot around the gardener is than the red herring. What you are describing seems to be more generally a technique of maintaining suspense of the will-they, won't they variety. There is no red herring involved in your treatment of the soccer matches.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, at some I felt "red-herring" might be intended for something slightly different: a red herring implies inconsequentiality, whereas a twist is closer to the concept of reversal (analogous to how nonconformist is different to anticonformist).

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @Alexander's answer...

To me a red herring has always been a clue that diverts the reader's attention. It's most popular, I believe, in detective stories, where the red herring will point at one person as the criminal only to have the real criminal revealed later on. Thus, it makes the outcome less predictable. Before learning of the correct term for the technique, I use to think of it as "throwing sand to the readers's eyes" (literal translation of a Portuguese saying) because the objective was to keep the reader from seeing the (fictional) 'reality'.

Comment: Just FYI, the phrase in English is "pulling the wool over [the reader's] eyes." *Throwing sand* makes me think of the old Charles Atlas bodybuilding ads.

Answer (score 3):

For me, there is a right way and a wrong way to include red herrings or twists in a story.

**The wrong way**

Suddenly subvert the reader's expectations with a plot twist AKA "the rug-pull".

Interesting, I would consider that the example given above (the film "The Usual Suspects") is an example of a *bad* twist. Very few (if any) details in the 'reveal' sequence at the end are actually noticeable by viewers during the course of the movie.

**The right way**

Developing the plot such that multiple endings are plausible before the red herrings are removed and the reader is left with the 'real' ending.

Right now, I can't think of a better example than the first "Mission Impossible" movie with Tom Cruise. As the film progresses and the protagonist reveals more information, he re-visits his memories to theorise and subsequently eliminate different possibilities.

EDIT: To more directly address the question: building up multiple plausible endings before picking one is incredibly satisfying to read and write. Savvy readers may attempt to guess the correct ending and feel rewarded and satisfied by the story's conclusion. Other readers will just enjoy the ride, but will still greatly appreciate how the set of possible endings will narrow as the story approaches the end.

Comment: I want to add that it is not always pleasing for the reader (or viewer) to get the right answer. If it is too straight forward, it becomes very boring. A few red herrings (in this case, multiple plausible possibilities for whodunit) make for a more entertaining story. For example, years ago there was a mystery show starring Dick Van Dyke (can't think of the name of the show). I would watch the first five minutes, predict the killer, leave the room, and return in the last 5 minutes to find out I was right. Never bothered to watch the whole show because it was too easy.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you describe a plot progression as "normal outcome - red herring - unexpected outcome". I see "red herring" as a very popular plot device without any "normal outcome" prelude. For example, the movie "Usual Suspects" is one big red herring.